# should i use remmove and is this correct in java?

Tags: java

in the exercise they told if string contain 00 or  0 remove it

```
String rse="12+00+9+88";

String re="[0]{1,2}\\+";
String oper[]=chaine.split("[0-9]{1,2}\\+");
for(int i=1;i<oper.length;i++) {
    if (oper.equals(re)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If the string contains 00 you can simply check by using the method contains. And then you can replace the zeros with empty string "" using replaceAll() method of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may juse use `String.replaceAll` and use 2 regexes

- `(0+)\+` to remove zeros followed by a `+`
- `\+(0+)`, specific case when zeros are the last one, the `+` is before it

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(
    "12+00+9+88",
    "12+0+9+88",
    "00+9+88",
    "0+9+88",
    "12+00",
    "12+0"
);

for (String s : values) {
    String r = s.replaceAll("(0+)\\+", "").replaceAll("\\+(0+)", "");
    System.out.println(r);
}

12+9+88
12+9+88
9+88
9+88
12
12
```